# Is there a way to quickly check what attribute the data is in a cell in a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I know we can easily convert or change the attribute to of data in a cell quickly and there are shortcuts for it but is there a way to check if a data or list of data in a column is saved as an int/string/date/etc?

I would like to be able to just quickly check if the data I have in a column is saved in the correct format/attribute without having to convert/change it again just to make sure.

Comment: Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel will make assumptions of what the data is automatically. There is no datatype like in python or other coding languages. There are functions for testing cells values.

Functions to look at `istext(), isblank(), isnumber(), islogical(), iserr(), ...`

so if you want to know the data type in B5.

```
=IFS(ISTEXT(B5),"String",ISBLANK(B5),"Null",ISNUMBER(B5),"Number",ISLOGICAL(B5),"Boolean",ISERR(B5),"Error")
```

To convert a number to a string use the single quote mark prior to the number like `'50`. A date in excel is also a number. To convert a number stored as a string into a number multiply by 1.

Edit---

There is a fuction [=Cell() see the details here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)
`=CELL("format",B5)`